# How to solve 'syntax error, unexpected LE' in QGIS query builder?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, error, query

I have a very simple question about the advanced query builder in QGIS.

I'd like to search for a range of numerical data values in the attribute table, but asking QGIS to show me values that are <= the low value and >= the high value doesn't seem to work; I continuously get a message that says:

> syntax error, unexpected LE

although sometimes is says GE instead of LE.

Haven't a clue what GE and/or LE refer to and can't find it on the internet.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the query builder and the message]

This should be easy but it's not, which generally means I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to supply the field ID for both the greater than and less than operations. This should work:

```
CELL_ID >= 106551 AND CELL_ID <= 247977
```

Comment: Oh Hallelujah.  Thanks Dan, that was driving me nuts.

Comment: @user22299 Dan is correct. The "Unexpected LE" means the expression parser encountered a "less than or equal to" (LE or <=) when it was expecting the field name.